# How to properly set ephemeral storage limits in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ephemeral-storage

I have the following k8s job definition:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: ephemeral-limit-test
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ephemeral-limit-test
        image: alpine
        command: ["sh", "-c"]
        args: ["cd /tmp && truncate -s 200M dummy && pwd && ls -lh dummy"]
        resources:
          requests:
            ephemeral-storage: "100Mi"
          limits:
            ephemeral-storage: "100Mi"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: ephemeral
          mountPath: "/tmp"
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
        - name: ephemeral
          emptyDir:
            sizeLimit: "100Mi"
  backoffLimit: 4
```

As we can see I set both the ephemeral storage request and limit to 100Mi, same as the `emptyDir sizeLimit`.

The output of the job is

```
/tmp                                                                                                                                                                                                           
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      200.0M Sep 18 14:01 dummy
```

How is it possible for the job to finish successfully before being evicted, after creating a file with size 200MB?